# Найдите среднюю стоимость акций за полгода( правая рекурсия)

Tags: prolog

/*Правая рекурсия*/

/**Стоимость акций известной фирмы стабильно растѐт на протяжении 6 месяцев, каждый месяц на 0,6%. Найдите среднюю стоимость акций за эти полгода, если известно, что начальная стоимость их была К у.е. **/

```
run:-
write('Введите начальную стоимость акций: '),nl,
read(A),nl,
rez(6).

rez(N):-
N>=1,write(A),write(' '),N1 is N-1,A1 is A+(A*0.6),write(A1),rez(N1).
rez(_).
```

Почему то не работает этот цикл

Comment: 0,6% от А - это А*0.006...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*Правая рекурсия*/
/**Стоимость акций известной фирмы стабильно раст?т на протяжении 6 месяцев, каждый месяц на 0,6%. Найдите среднюю стоимость акций за эти полгода, если известно, что начальная стоимость их была К у.е. **/

run:-
write('Введите начальную стоимость акций: '),nl,
read(A),nl,
S is A,
rez(6,A,S).

rez(N,A,S):-
N>1,
/**write(A),
write(' '),*/
N1 is N-1,
A1 is A*1.006,
/**write(A1),*/
S1 is S+A1,
rez(N1,A1,S1).

rez(_,A,S):-
write('Средняя стоимость за год равна: '),SUM is S/6,write(SUM).
```

Answer (score 0):

> Почему то не работает этот цикл

Пространство имён переменных Пролога - предложение ( clause ).

Так что, **A** в `read(A), nl,` не имеет никакого отношения к **A** в `N>=1,write(A)`.

Позтому второе **A** - *несвязанная переменная* , это и есть причина некорректной работы программы.

Вам следует передать **A** в `rez` как второй аргумент.

Кстати, ошибка, на которую было указано выше в комметарии `0.6% == 0.006` присутствует и в коде:
`A1 is A+(A*0.6),` вместо этого фрагмента мог бы быть такой 
`A1 is A*1.006,`